# @RequestMapping does not work with GET request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-annotations

I am trying get a simple spring boot app working on Mac.
I am using the following 
port:8080 also tried 8085, 8081

in postman:http://localhost:8080/root/sayHi GET-Request

but the result I am getting in error..I have done the same example on windows but it was working

please let me know how to fix this error

**code**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/root")
class Demo2Application


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
runApplication<Demo2Application>(*args)
}

@RequestMapping("/sayHi", method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.GET))
@ResponseBody
fun sayHi() : String {
return "..hi"
}
```

Comment: Try `@GetMapping("/sayHi")fun sayHi() : String {`

Comment: `@RequestMapping` should be like this `@RequestMapping(path = "/sayHi", method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.GET))`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try separating the main class from the controller class. Spring boot follows the MVC architecture and it's better to keep the logic separate from the main class. The `@Controller` annotation etc might not work was expected when used in the main class itself.

```
@SpringBootApplication
class Demo2Application {
  fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   runApplication<Demo2Application>(*args)
  }   
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/root")
class HelloRestController {

  @GetMapping("/sayHi") // or @RequestMapping(value= "/sayHi", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  fun sayHi() : String {
   return "..hi"
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestMapping` methods needs to be in `@RestController` class - spring scan for `@Controller` classes, then it is looking for all `@RequestMapping` methods of that class. But your class ends in the same line that it starts (because there is lack of braces {} telling where is a class body).

To fix your problem, you need to move your `@RequestMapping` function before main function and open class body before `fun sayHi` and close right after that:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/root")
class Demo2Application { // ******* this opens class body ********

    @RequestMapping("/sayHi", method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.GET))
    @ResponseBody
    fun sayHi() : String {
        return "..hi"
    }
} // ******* this closes class body *********

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Demo2Application>(*args)
}
```

When you put function in class body in kotlin - its the same as java method inside class body. But when you put function directly in file (outside of class body) - its like static method in java. Additionally these static methods from kotlin - in JVM will appear in different class: `FileNameKt` (for example for file `demo.kt` your function `sayHi()` will appear in JVM as static method `DemoKt.sayHi()`, not as the member of `Demo2Application` instance method